# How can get all Key Frames(Key Ticks) in 3DS Max using its SDK

Tags: 3dsmax

Right now I can get all Key Frames(Key Ticks) out of My skinned Model using 3DS API, if my model has a 
Transform Controller and at the same time this transform controller has Translation Controller and Rotation Controller
using:
  Control* pos_max_controller = current_igame_node->GetMaxNode()->GetTMController()->GetPositionController();
  Control* rot_max_controller = current_igame_node->GetMaxNode()->GetTMController()->GetRotationController();

But I found, a skinned model can also have other kinds of transformation controllers underneath that Transform Controller(maybe Some Spline Controller).

But in this case, I just can get that translation controller( even if it is not lying underneath TM Controller). 
And that rot_max_controller in this case is always 0.

How can I handle any kinds of Transform Controller with any kinds of kid controllers using the 3DS Max API?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to get out the bone transformations? or mesh transformation? (I think your question is a little confusing).

Comment: i am wanting to get out the bone transforms of each key frame as defined on that Animation Track.

Comment: What I do is this (let me know if that's what you want too, I can post code for you):
1) Loop through all bones in skin modifier.
2) for each bone loop through animation range and get world\parent transformation.
3) create keyframes for every X frame in max in the format I'm exporting to.

Doing it that way you get the transformation regardless of what controller is used (IK and such as well).

Comment: thank for you reply. could you please post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from one of my exporter that I've done for a game engine.
Instead of going into the controller to read out the data, I get the node itself and read from the node directly, this means that the bones can be animated in any way and still export fine.

```
 //jountCount is the number of bones in the skin modifier,
        for (int currbone=0;currbone<jointCount;currbone++)
        {
            int time = GetCOREInterface()->GetTime();

        INode* boneNode = skin->GetBone(currbone);
        //animEnd and anim Begin is set in my GUI. for example frame 10 to 100
        int totalKeyframeTime = animEnd - (animBegin);
        int myticks = GetTicksPerFrame();

        fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t<Bone id=\"%i\">\n",currbone);
        fprintf(s_pStreammma, "\t\t<position num=\"%i\">\n",totalKeyframeTime);

        Point3 ang;
        Matrix3 nodeTM2;
        Matrix3 objTM2;
        Point3 objTrans2;
        TimeValue tval;

        for(int v = 0; v < totalKeyframeTime; ++v)
        {
            tval = TimeValue(animBegin +v);
            nodeTM2 = boneNode->GetNodeTM(tval * myticks);
            objTM2 = boneNode->GetObjectTM(tval * myticks);
            objTrans2 = objTM2.GetTrans();
            INode *parent = node->GetParentNode();
            Matrix3 parent_TM = parent->GetNodeTM(tval * myticks);
            Matrix3 local_tm = (parent_TM - objTM2);

            if(currbone == 0)
            {
                parent = node;
            }
            else
            {
                parent = boneNode->GetParentNode();
            }
            Matrix3 localTransform = nodeTM2 * Inverse(parent->GetNodeTM(tval * myticks));
            Point3 vLocalPos = localTransform.GetTrans();
            fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t\t<k t=\"%i\" x=\"%f\" y=\"%f\" z=\"%f\"/>\n",(animBegin +v),vLocalPos.x,vLocalPos.y,vLocalPos.z);
        }
        fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t</position>\n");
        fprintf(s_pStreammma, "\t\t<rotation num=\"%i\">\n",totalKeyframeTime);

        for(int v = 0; v < totalKeyframeTime; ++v)
        {
            tval = TimeValue(animBegin +v);
            INode *parent = node->GetParentNode();
            Matrix3 parent_TM = parent->GetNodeTM(tval * myticks);
            nodeTM2 = boneNode->GetNodeTM(tval * myticks);
            objTM2 = boneNode->GetObjectTM(tval * myticks);

            if(currbone == 0)
            {
                parent = node;
            }
            else
            {
                parent = boneNode->GetParentNode();
            }
            Matrix3 local_tm = nodeTM2 * Inverse(parent->GetNodeTM(tval * myticks));
            QuatToEuler(local_tm,ang,0,false);
            fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t\t<k t=\"%i\" x=\"%f\" y=\"%f\" z=\"%f\"/>\n",(animBegin +v),ang.x /3.14*180,ang.y /3.14*180,ang.z /3.14*180);
        }
        fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t</rotation>\n");

        //scale
        fprintf(s_pStreammma, "\t\t<scale num=\"%i\">\n",totalKeyframeTime);
        for(int v = 0; v < totalKeyframeTime; ++v)
        {
            fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t\t<k t=\"%i\" x=\"%f\" y=\"%f\" z=\"%f\"/>\n",(animBegin +v),1.0,1.0,1.0);
        }
        fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t</scale>\n");
        fprintf(s_pStreammma,"\t\t</Bone>\n");
        animStartTimeTemp +=1;
    }
```

To get keyframes, and get the time of these keyframes from the bone objects you can use the following code, remember to adjust for rotation  \ scale keys as well.

```
Control *c;
                c = boneNode->GetTMController()->GetPositionController();

                IKeyControl *ikeys = GetKeyControlInterface(c);
                if (!ikeys) return;
                int numkeys = rootBone->NumKeys();
                IKey* mykey;
                for (int key=0;key < numkeys; key++)
                {
                    ikeys->GetKey(key,mykey);
                    TimeValue keytime;
                    keytime = mykey->time;

                }
```

for biped it lists the position controller as 'BipPositionList', and not the regular 'Position XYZ controller' that a regular bone has. So you need to customize the code by getting the biped BipPositionList and write out the data from there.

Comment: from you code snapshot, it seems to export the bone transforms in an frame interval(from the Begin to End). I think you code just simply export all frames(maybe 1000 frames, if you want so) without considering if the current frame is a key frame or not. It will have more data than necessary. What i want is just output each frame, if there is a key transform(translation or rotation) on that frame.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I write out on a frame-by-frame basis.
 I edited my answer so that you can see how to get keyframes out of your bone object and loop through, you can use that in combination with the other code to easily detect when to write out transformation data.

Comment: thank you for posting your code. I just checked your code on the line, where you are trying to get the PositionController from a Bone Node. But some skinned model doesn't have it. please take a look at the model downloaded from http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/cartoon-cow-7742.html. I am just wondering why that positional controller is null. thx

Comment: It seems to be because the model you are exporting is made with Biped, and if you look at the 'motion' panel for a bone in the biped it lists the position controller as 'BipPositionList', and not the regular 'Position XYZ controller' that a regular bone has.

So you need to customize the code by getting the biped BipPositionList and write out the data from there.

I do not have code for that at the moment, but It's next on my own list over what to do.

Here is a 'biped to bones' script that makes your biped into regular bones, . http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/character-on-biped

Comment: The 'biped to bones' script failed due to it making all the bones to big, but it might work if set up properly.

Comment: I edited my reply to also include info about the biped, if you feel my answer covers what you need then feel free to mark it as 'accepted', It makes it easier for others to quickly find answer, and also for them to see that you have a answer to your question.

Comment: one another question: is it possible just using C code to convert that Biped into normal controllers. Or some other way to get all keyframe's data

Comment: The way I did it on our end was to export to FBX and import the model again, during import it will then convert it to regular max bones and it exports easily. This would be the same as baking the biped animation.

Comment: Beware that some of the bones getting imported can have the same names, so if you depend on the bone names then you have to rename them all with the rename tool, if not you'll end up with some duplicate names if you use CAT rigging tool.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out that duplicated bone names and how to convert into normal max bone using export and import via FBX

Comment: One last thing I forgot to mention is that when you import it back in it some times does not apply all imported bones to the new skin, so just make sure to add them all by adding the ones not assigned manually. reason is if you check the 'skin' for bones to export, then some of them are not there, that breaks the parent\child transformations on export, since it cannot find the bone's parent, but everything looks good in 3dsmax viewport because the bones is in the hierarchy.

Comment: I have tried a few example animated models, also ran the sample 3ds exporter project. It seems you can never access the keyframes. 3ds exporter parses the animation by a fixed value per frame instead. I can see the keyframes in Max. Why is this?